# Probability of an event if r out of n events were true.

Tags: probability, integration, summation, binomial-coefficients

I need to calculate what is the probability that the next event will be true if r out of n events were true.
It is given that the probability for all events is equal and the probability is evenly distributed between 0 and 1.

I tried it myself and got stuck at an integral.
$$ \frac{\int_0^1 \binom{n}{r}p^{r+1} (1-p)^{n-r}dp}{\int_0^1 \binom{n}{r} p^r (1-p)^{n-r}dp}$$
I think this integral evaluates to $\frac{r+1}{n+2}$ but I haven't had much success.

If it helps , the closest I think i have gotten is
$$ \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n-r} \frac{(-1)^i \binom{n-r}{i}}{r+i+2}}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-r} \frac{(-1)^i \binom{n-r}{i}}{r+i+1}} $$

Comment: What distribution?

Comment: Evenly distributed between 0 and 1

Comment: I got $\frac{1+r}{n+2}$ using Mathematica.

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to prove it.

Comment: See [rule of succession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession).

Comment: See also my related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3514574).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can evaluate the integrals using repeated integration by parts. The boundary terms vanish, and in the denominator you accumulate exactly the factors in $\binom nr$ and one additional factor $\frac1{n+1}$.

The quotient comes out as

$$
\frac{\frac{r+1}{(n+1)(n+2)}}{\frac1{n+1}}=\frac{r+1}{n+2}\;.
$$

Here’s the integration by parts for the denominator; the one for the numerator works analogously:

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^1p^r(1-p)^{n-r}\mathrm dp
&=&
\left[-\frac{p^r(1-p)^{n-r+1}}{n-r+1}\right]_0^1+\int_0^1\frac{rp^{r-1}(1-p)^{n-r+1}}{n-r+1}\mathrm dp
\\&=&\frac r{n-r+1}\int_0^1p^{r-1}(1-p)^{n-r+1}\mathrm dp
\\&=&\frac{r(r-1)}{(n-r+1)(n-r+2)}\int_0^1p^{r-2}(1-p)^{n-r+2}\mathrm dp
\\&=&\cdots
\\&=&\frac{r!(n-r)!}{n!}\int_0^1(1-p)^n\mathrm dp
\\&=&\frac{r!(n-r)!}{n!}\cdot\frac1{n+1}\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I am not very adept at calculus so I don't know what to apply integration by parts on. I did try using it.

Comment: @adityajain: I added the integration by parts for the denominator to the answer. The factor $p^r$ is repeatedly differentiated, the factor $(1-p)^{n-r}$ is repeatedly integrated. (You could also do it the other way around.)

Comment: You can avoid the integration by parts if you recognize the integral as $$B(r+1,n-r+1)=\frac{r!(n-r)!}{(n+1)!}.$$

Comment: Oh i didnt think of recursion